# Is it okay to change public variables within functions, or is this bad practice?

Tags: vb.net, function, module, public, subroutine

I am creating a module that interfaces with another person's main code, so this is what I came up with. One sub reads the values from the main module and sets the public variables. The other function calls the setVariables function and then performs a calculation using the set values. My function will be called in the main module (Module1). Is this good coding practice, or is there a better way to do this?

For example:

```
Module Module2
    Public x as Single
    Public y as Single
    Public z as Single

    Public Function calculate(i as Short, j as Short) as Single
        setVariables(i, j)
        r = x^2 + y^2 + z^2
        return r
    End Function

    Public Sub setVariables(i as Short, j as Short)
        x = Module1.structure1(i).structure2(j).valuex
        y = Module1.structure1(i).structure2(j).valuey
        z = Module1.structure1(i).structure2(j).valuez
    End Sub
End Module
```

Edit: Here's an example of what Module1 looks like:

```
Module Module1
    ' declare Public Structures
    ' do stuff
    ' do more stuff
    Private Sub doThisThing()
        ' do some stuff
        For i = 1 To 10
            For j = 1 To 10
                r(i,j) = Module2.calculate(i,j)
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: There's some surprising coupling going on between `Module1` and `Module2`.  In general, I'd recommend against having two different things each poking around at each other's internals---I think this looks like an issue that's sometimes formalized as the "Law of Demeter".  I'd be a lot less skeptical of this if `setVariables` were referencing something within `Module2`, then it's more expected.  You might want to consider passing those things in as arguments rather than referencing them directly.

Comment: Also, the use of `Structure` makes me nervous.  Be very, very careful with `Structure`s.  They're very easy to get wrong in ways that will give mysterious-looking behavior.  You should be very skeptical of any `Structure` that doesn't have all members `ReadOnly` and initialized in the ctor.

Comment: That looks like a weird circular dependency. If `Module1` will call that method, why not change its definition to accept the values it needs to calculate? Since `Module2` is *injected* in `Module1`, it should know nothing about `Module2` an its internal Structures. Classes and interfaces are probably better when creating this kind of *relation*.

Comment: @Jimi, `Module1` knows nothing about `Module2`. It's `Module2`, which is taking data from `Module1`, processing it in a bunch of ways, and then returning the result. The example I gave is much more simplified but basically shows the communication channel.

Comment: *Module1 knows nothing about Module2*: Module1 is calling `Module2.calculate(i,j)`, so it knows, but that's not the problem. Anyway, that's the opposite of what I meant to say, probably because I inverted the names in: *Since Module2 is injected in Module1, it should know nothing about Module2*, where of course I meant *...it should know nothing about Module1*. -- The problem is that you're using a function in Module2 called from Module1 to calculate values in Module1, when the data in Module2 is taken from Module1 using structures and fields made public. That's circular. Bound to disaster.

Comment: So far it works fine. I just had a hunch that this isn't the proper way to do things; that's why I am asking. Module1 is already fully functioning GUI which takes a bunch of input data, and displays some results on the screen. Module2 reads a completely different set of data, brings in some of the data collected by Module1, performs some calculations, and spits it back to Module1 for display. Is there a clean way to get the data out of Module1? Or should I dump all 20 of my subroutines into the bottom of Module1 and get rid of Module2? Also, thank you for your advice, I truly appreciate it.

Comment: Change `calculate()` to accept `x`, `y` and `z` values and return the calculation. These values belong to Module1 and can be passed to the method from there, without returning to Module1 from Module2 to fetch the data used for the calculation, when the value is then returned to Module1. -- As mentioned, classes and Interfaces are made for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Note that there's [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for this kind of questions.

Comment: @Jimi when suggesting users post on CR it would be great if there was also a suggestion like "_Please read the relevant help center pages like '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and  '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_". In the current form the post above would likely be closed as off-topic because it [is missing context](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/my-question-was-closed-as-being-off-topic-what-are-my-options/3652#3652)/too hypothetical, which happens often.

Comment: @Sᴀᴍ Onᴇᴌᴀ Yes, I know. I didn't flag the question as more suitable for that site. I suggested that in Codereview this kind of question is more likely to find an non-opinionated answer (per SO requirements). I assume the OP, should they opt to migrate, will rework the question in a way that is appropriate for CR.

Comment: Many users assume that but sadly it frequently isn't the case.

Comment: @Sᴀᴍ Onᴇᴌᴀ That happens anywhere, SO included, no matter how much you try to avoid it. As mentioned, there's no flagged request to migrate. I won't instead assume that the OP cannot *read the manual*.

Answer (score 0):

It works.. This by itself might mean that it is was worth doing so, in this scenario. But if you move the 2 modules between different libraries / projects, references might get circular, causing it to not load in correctly. or causing it not to compile at all.

The law in programming is, that you never make things 'depend' back on its accesor.

An workaround can be to define the structure in the other module, and pass the object to calculate() instead of its coordinates.